# How do I stop Microsoft Teams from converting smileys to emojis?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Whenever I try to type a smiley face in Microsoft Teams, it gets automatically converted into an emoji. This means `:)` -> , `<3` -> `❤` , etc. Other chat applications like Discord have options to disable auto-emoji, but Teams seems to be missing this.

How do I stop Microsoft Teams from auto-converting smileys into emojis?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft Teams does not have a way to disable automatic conversion of smileys to emojis. As a workaround, you can undo the emoji conversion by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: Undo emoji with Ctrl+Z]

Comment: It makes me sad that this is the best solution. Why force autocorrect on users for any purpose? :(

Comment: In the markdown of this answer is a link to https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8w73.gif that is not used anywhere. What was it for?

Comment: @cachius That image was leftover from an unposted revision that suggested code formatting the smiley before I discovered the Ctrl+Z trick.

Answer (score 4):

there is a workaround. If you type the smiley in MS Teams it will be converted. But if you type the smiley in e.g. Notepad and copy & paste it in Teams it won't be converted. Not the best solution, but it works..

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the accepted answer?

Comment: Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓)  ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: @DarkDiamond I would consider this a valid alternative solution. It's different enough from the accepted answer to be worth posting.

Answer (score 2):

If you type the space *very*(!) quickly after the character completing the smiley, it will not be replaced.

[image: Fast space prevents smiley replacement]

Answer (score 2):

I found out a few minutes ago that after you complete typing the smiley, which gets converted after you *type a space*, use Ctrl+Z and Teams un-converts it.

You must type the space **after** the smiley because if you use Ctrl+Z to un-convert it, typing the space will re-convert it.

That worked for me in both the app and web version of Teams.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried everything to no avail. We have an Accounts Payable department. When I typed Accounts Payable (AP) the "(AP)" became and airplane. Trying all the suggestions in this post were no help. Hitting CNTL-Z after the airplane appeared did return the text "(AP)" -- but hitting the spacebar caused the airplane to return. Typing '(AP)' in Notepad, then copying and pasting immediately produced an airplane.

This is really unacceptable. That a product, especially from a company like Microsoft (I would expect it from Apple) would provide no way to undo these annoying conversions is unbelievable. Highly unprofessional.

Children must be in charge.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1223058)

Answer (score 1):

I've also learned that if you make the smileys upside down it doesn't detect them.
Only works for some obviously, but it's better than nothing